# How to know what exceptions fromHtml throws?

Tags: android

Do we need to catch any exceptions while using fromHtml("HTMLString")

Answer (score 0):

2 EXCEPTIONS

org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException  and 
org.xml.sax.SAXNotSupportedException

U can check the sources for that  http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/SAXNotSupportedException.html

Comment: How can we force fromHtml() to throw these exceptions?

Comment: You cannot force .... becoz Html.fromHtml does not throws Any EXCEPTION ... by default it will not use throws..

Comment: I am confused from your two answers :) You said we need to catch two exceptions while using fromHtml(), but now u say fromHtml() does not throw any exception.

Comment: see http://pastebin.com/7yGbbwVE THIS IS THE SOUCE CODE OF Html class file in this u can observe fromHtml() catches 2 exceptions but it will not throw any Exception. If it throws then only u can catch other wise u can to give that inside a try - catch block ...to catch it manually

Comment: If u still confused consider this case **URL url = new URL(string);** u have to give the above statement in try catch block becoz it catches and throws the exception ... but fromHtml() will catch the Exception but it will not throw

Comment: throw new RuntimeException(e); this line in Html.fromHtml() means its throwing exception right. Sorry if I am not being clear.

I am receiving an html string from third party, I want to make sure not to messup my screen if the third party sends some messy html string.